# Resolve symbol definition filename from import usage via typescript compiler APIs

Tags: typescript, module

I have the following task:

Given an input filename (e.g. `@lib/a/index.ts`), resolve the filename that defines the symbol.

`f(inputFilename, symbolName) => resolvedSymbolFilename`

Concretely, here's a hypothetical set of files:

```
// @lib/a/index.ts
import { thing } from "@lib/x"
```

```
// @lib/x/index.ts
export * from "./things"
```

```
// @lib/x/things.ts
export const thing = () => { ... };
```

Thus, `f("/path/to/@lib/a/index.ts", "thing") => "/path/to/@lib/x/things.ts"`. Note that there may be various traversals of modules between `@lib/a` & `@lib/x/things.ts`.

Are there concise and/or sugar compiler APIs to achieve this?